# Regarding classes in python

Tags: python, class

I have basic question about python classes. I would like to access
a class member defined in one python file across different files. Here is my code:

I have one python file `class_A.py`:

```
class A:

def Hello(self):
    self.a=12
    print "printing A value from class_1",self.a
```

Here is the code of class_B.py file

```
import Class_A

def func_B():
   Instance = Class_A.A()
   Instance.Hello()

func_B()
```

When I execute, it shows:

```
TypeError: Hello() takes no arguments (1 given).
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is accessing class members defined in `class_A.py`
by creating an instance to that class inside the function `func_B` which is defined
in another python file `Class_B.py`. Is this right?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you posted. Do you have any additional code in your class_B.py file?

Comment: Not sure if it is the layout of the question or your actual python layout, but I think you need to indent the def Hello(self): and the body one more time to make sure they are part of the class A :)

Comment: I think you may actually not define classes at all. In python, it's not the case that a defined method becomes a class member just because of a file name. Please post your full code, properly formatted.

Comment: def Hello(self): should be indented to be inside class A

Comment: Should `import Class_A` be `import class_A`?

Comment: This is not your actual code. If the method `Hello` is indented, it works. If it's not, you'll get an error that class A is empty (no `pass`).

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is with the indentation in the `class A`:

```
class A:
    def Hello(self):
        self.a = 12
        print "printing A value from class_1", self.a
```

Aside: Take a look a the [`PEP8`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide.

Comment: Ah, expected that it could be a indent issue, but seriously you never know here on stack as people always fail to format their code.